# SendGrid handling multiple environments

Tags: sendgrid

Couldn't find any info on that: does anyone know if SendGrid supports anyhow multiple environments?

I'm talking specifically about webhooks and seems that you can have only one webhook at a time where it would be nice to have separate for dev, stage and production environment while having one template base.

Comment: Any luck on supporting multiple environments with SendGrid?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we have separate URL set up for sendgrid webhooks for different environment like Test, Stage and Prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001922/can-we-have-separate-url-set-up-for-sendgrid-webhooks-for-different-environment)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found https://postmarkapp.com/ - so far the only one really supporting multiple environments independently.